# Flink table exception : Window aggregate can only be defined over a time attribute column, but TIMESTAMP(6) encountered

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I am using flink 1.12.0. Trying to convert a data stream into a table A and running the sql query on the tableA to aggregate over a window as below.I am using f2 column as its a timestamp data type field .

```
    EnvironmentSettings fsSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inStreamingMode().build();

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, fsSettings);

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
    props.setProperty("schema.registry.url", xxx);
    props.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    props.setProperty("value.deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());

    props.put("client.id", "flink-kafka-example");

    FlinkKafkaConsumer<PlaybackListening> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
            "test-topic",
            ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(
                    Avrotest.class, prodSchemaRegistryURL),
            props);

    DataStreamSource<Avrotest> stream =
            env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);
    Table tableA = tEnv.fromDataStream(stream, $("f0"), $("f1"),$("f2"));
    Table result =
            tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT f0, sum(f1),f2 FROM "
                    + tableA + " GROUP BY TUMBLE(f2, INTERVAL '1' HOUR) ,f1" );

    
    tEnv.toAppendStream(result,user.class).print();

    env.execute("Flink kafka test");
}
```

When i execute above code,i get

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Window aggregate can only be defined over a time attribute column, but TIMESTAMP(6) encountered.
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.StreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.getInAggregateGroupExpression(StreamLogicalWindowAggregateRule.scala:50)
at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.rules.logical.LogicalWindowAggregateRuleBase.onMatch(LogicalWindowAggregateRuleBase.scala:81)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.AbstractRelOptPlanner.fireRule(AbstractRelOptPlanner.java:333)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRule(HepPlanner.java:542)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.applyRules(HepPlanner.java:407)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepPlanner.executeInstruction(HepPlanner.java:243)
at org.apache.calcite.plan.hep.HepInstruction$RuleInstance.execute(HepInstruction.java:127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do using the table API to perform event-time windowing on your datastream, you'll need to first assign timestamps and watermarks. You should do this before calling `fromDataStream`.

With Kafka, it's generally best to call `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks` directly on the `FlinkKafkaConsumer`. See the [watermark docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector), [kafka connector docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-timestamp-extractionwatermark-emission), and [Flink SQL docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/time_attributes.html#introduction-to-time-attributes) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps:

1. First assign `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks`

You have several types of strategies.

For example:

```
 WatermarkStrategy<Row> customTime = WatermarkStrategy
                .<Row>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> (long) event.getField("f2"));
```

2. In your source assign what you declare in step 1:

```
env.addSource().assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(customTime)
```

3. declare the table, and set rowtime for the timestamp field:

```
Table tableA = tEnv.fromDataStream(stream, $("f0"), $("f1"),$("f2").rowtime());
```