# Set WatermarkStrategy for Event Timestamps

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to do a windowed aggregation query on a data stream that contains over 40 attributes in Flink. The stream's schema contains an epoch timestamp which I want to use for the WatermarkStrategy so I can actually define tumbling windows over it.

I know from the [docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/concepts/time_attributes/#defining-in-ddl), that you can define a Timestamp using the SQL Api in an `CREATE TABLE`-query by first using `TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ` on the epochs to convert it to a proper timestamp which can be used in the following `WATERMARK FOR`-statement. Since I got a really huge schema tho, I want to deserialise and provide the schema NOT by completely writing the complete `CREATE TABLE`-statement containing all columns BUT by using a custom class derived from the proto file that cointains the schema. As far as I know, this is only possible by providing a deserializer for the KafkaSourceBuilder and calling the `results` function of the stream on the class derived from the protofile with `protoc`. Which means, that I have to define the table using the stream api.

Inspired by the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66204166/flink-table-exception-window-aggregate-can-only-be-defined-over-a-time-attribu), I do it like this:

```
        WatermarkStrategy watermarkStrategy = WatermarkStrategy
                .<Row>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .withTimestampAssigner( (event, ts) -> (Long) event.getField("ts"));
        
        tableEnv.createTemporaryView(
                "bidevents",
                stream
                        .returns(BiddingEvent.BidEvent.class)
                        .map(e -> Row.of(
                                e.getTracking().getCampaign().getId(),
                                e.getTracking().getAuction().getId(),
                                Timestamp.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(e.getTimestamp().getMilliseconds() / 1000))
                            )
                        )
                        .returns(Types.ROW_NAMED(new String[] {"campaign_id", "auction_id", "ts"}, Types.STRING, Types.STRING, Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP))
                        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(watermarkStrategy)
        );


        tableEnv.executeSql("DESCRIBE bidevents").print();

        Table resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery("" +
                "SELECT " +
                "   TUMBLE_START(ts, INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS window_start, " +
                "   TUMBLE_END(ts, INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS window_end, " +
                "   campaign_id, " +
                "   count(distinct auction_id) auctions " +
                "FROM bidevents " +
                "GROUP BY TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '1' DAY), campaign_id");

        DataStream<Row> resultStream = tableEnv.toDataStream(resultTable);
        resultStream.print();
        env.execute();
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Window aggregate can only be defined over a time attribute column, but TIMESTAMP(9) encountered.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372) ~[flink-dist-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:291) ~[flink-dist-1.15.1.jar:1.15.1]
```

This seems kind of logical, since in `line 3` I cast a java.sql.Timestamp to a Long value, which it is not (but also the stacktrace does not indicate that an error occurred during the cast). But when I do not convert the epoch (in Long-Format) during the `map`-statement to a Timestamp, I get this exception:

```
"Cannot apply '$TUMBLE' to arguments of type '$TUMBLE(<BIGINT>, <INTERVAL DAY>)'"
```

How can I assign the watermark AFTER the `map`-statement and use the column in the later SQL Query to create a tumbling window?

**======UPDATE=====**

Thanks to a comment from David, I understand that I need the column to be of type `TIMESTAMP(p)` with precision `p <= 3`. To my understanding this means, that my timestamp may not be more precise than having full milliseconds. So i tried different ways to create Java Timestamps (java.sql.Timestamps and java.time.LocaleDateTime) which correspond to the Flink timestamps.
Some examples are:

**1** Trying to convert epochs into a LocalDateTime by setting `nanoseconds` (the 2nd parameter of `ofEpochSecond` to 0):

```
LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(e.getTimestamp().getMilliseconds() / 1000, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

**2** After reading the answer from Svend in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68617522/how-to-map-java-localdatetime-to-flink-timestamp-when-using-table-api) who uses `LocalDateTime.parse` on timestamps that look like this `"2021-11-16T08:19:30.123"`, I tried this:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(
            LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                  Instant.ofEpochSecond(e.getTimestamp().getMilliseconds() / 1000),
                  ZoneId.systemDefault()
            )
      )
)
```

As you can see, the timestamps even only have seconds-granularity (which i checked when looking at the printed output of the stream I created) which I assume should mean, they have a precision of 0. But actually when using this stream for defining a table/view, it once again has the type `TIMESTAMP(9)`.

**3** I also tried it with the sql timestamps:

```
new Timestamp(e.getTimestamp().getMilliseconds() )
```

This also did not change anything. I somehow always end up with a precision of 9.

Can somebody please help me how I can fix this?

Comment: You need to somehow get it to be a TIMESTAMP(3) rather than a TIMESTAMP(9).

Comment: Thank you, David! I will try that out tomorrow. Your answers here are so valuable and I am always happy to stumble upon them. :)

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried to achieve what you suggested, but I somehow have problems with this. I updated the question respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution to the problem. If you got a stream containing a timestamp which you want to define as event time column for watermarks, you can use this function:

```
Table inputTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(
                stream,
                Schema.newBuilder()
                        .column("campaign_id", "STRING")
                        .column("auction_id", "STRING")
                        .column("ts", "TIMESTAMP(3)")
                        .watermark("ts", "SOURCE_WATERMARK()")
                        .build()
        );
```

The important part is, that you can "cast" the timestamp `ts` from TIMESTAMP(9)  "down" to TIMESTAMP(3) or any other precision below 4 and you can set the column to contain the water mark.

Another mention that seems important to me is, that only Timestamps of type `java.time.LocalDateTime` actually worked for later use as watermarks for tumbling windows.

Any other attempts to influence the precision of the timestamps by differently creating java.sql.Timestamp or java.time.LocalDateTime failed. This seemed to be the only viable way.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!